Azure App Service: 503 Service Unavailable After Enabling Local Cache for React App
I have deployed my React app to an Azure App Service running on the B1 tier. I am trying to enable local caching to improve performance. Here are the configurations I've set:
App Service Tier: B1
Environment Variables:
WEBSITE_LOCAL_CACHE_OPTION = Always
WEBSITE_LOCAL_CACHE_SIZEINMB = 2000
Initially, after applying these settings, the site loads correctly on the first browse. However, subsequent requests result in a "503 Service Unavailable" error.
I've verified that the configurations are correctly applied. What could be causing this issue, and how can I resolve it to ensure my app remains available after enabling local cache?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

What does your log stream show?

If possible can you share your github repo?




0
1
0
Keywords

518894234
Application
webwk000005



Failed to open siteversion.txt. ZipFS setup failed. Error: 0x80070003




0
1
0
Keywords

518894250
Application
webwk000005



Adding virtual directory from failure zip file \\?\d:\local\SitePackages\518889218.zip

This is my log stream . Image is attached as a link please check
https://ibb.co/McvJYKN

Restart the application site to get the latest changes applied, after adding the application settings.
If the cache size is too large for the available memory, it leads to performance issues or service unavailability. Reduce the cache size to <2000 MB.
Enable Application logs in App Service logs and check the logs of your application in Log Stream.

I have created a React app and deployed to Azure.
Enabled Local Cache using the settings:
WEBSITE_LOCAL_CACHE_OPTION
WEBSITE_LOCAL_CACHE_SIZEINMB


Also added Time limit setting WEBSITES_CONTAINER_START_TIME_LIMIT=1800 to avoid timeout issues.


Portal:

Could run the deployed application without any issues.



I am deploy my simple React app as a code in azure app service .
https://ibb.co/X7VfSc5
I have implemented these two variables by reducing size from 2000 to 1800 , 1500 , 1000
It browse good for first 2 , 3 call afterwards it restarts and gives 503 service unavailable
https://ibb.co/swCXkcj
Below is my log stream for this :
https://ibb.co/McvJYKN

Images are attached as a link . please also check

Can you please share the logstream again. The link is not available.

@TahamiRizwan, Is your issue resolved? If not, please provide the logstream.

yes my issue was resolved
